# Is it possible to highlight a keyword group in 'suffix mode' in Notepad++ User Defined Language?

Tags: notepad++

The User Defined Language model in Notepad++ (at least for version 7.X and above) allows for defining a Keyword group in 'Prefix mode'.

A good description is taken from [this blog post](http://www.thevalvepage.com/swmonkey/2015/08/19/notepad-user-defined-languages/):

> The more inquisitive of you may well be wondering what that **[Prefix mode]** checkbox is. Well it means the keyword just needs to be the starting characters e.g. if you untick this box and set a keyword of “*dont*” then only the exact word “*dont*” (give or take case sensitivity) will be treated as keywords. However if you tick this box then that one keyword will also match ***dont***givemegrief, ***dont***makemylifemisery, ***dont***forcewindows10onme, etc.

I couldn't find any mention of this in documentation or elsewhere, though: is it possible to define a keyword group in **"Suffix mode"**?

As an example the '*key*' keyword in Suffix mode should *not* match:

> keyword, key_test, key_1

But *should* match:

> ***key***, *test_**key***,